Can a PopupMenu within a Manipulate command include submenus?
Although not new to Mathematica (started on v6.0), I have never tried to create a PopupMenu that has submenus from within a Manipulate command. The relatively new ActionMenu command with its submenu feature could be made to work, but I haven't figured out how to incorporate it within the standard Manipulate control structure.
After days of trying and searching forums and online sites, I am concluding that this is not directly possible. Do I really have to build a DynamicModule version of Manipulate with all custom controls (or some equivalent)? Has any such code already been posted? Am I just missing something simple?
Thanks for any insight and help.
